# ROS documentation link redirects to wrong URL

Tags: ros, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

since some days; I've noticed that the Documentation link from http://www.ros.org/news/ redirects me to a wrong URL.

Clicking the link Documentation redirects me to an empty page http://www.ros.org/wiki/ and not as expected to http://wiki.ros.org/

Is it a local german problem ?

Thanks for checking this

Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275773/ros-documentation-link-redirects-to-wrong-url/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-11-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-13**:
Hi there, I don't see such link, would you mind adding a screenshot of which one are you referring to?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-13**:
I'm seeing this in the US as well. It's in documentation link in the banner across the top: `Documentation` `Browse Software` `News` `Download`.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-11-13**:
Note the `Download` link is broken as well, and the `Browse Software` link works, but only because of a redirection (the URL is old).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-11-13**:
I think it's an issue with our redirects (`www.ros.org/wiki/*` should redirect to `wiki.ros.org/*`). I'm working on it with our hosting people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've updated the links across the top of ros.org/news to use the new resource URLs and not rely on the redirects from the old locations.

As @William said, We're also working to restore the redirects for better backwards compatibility.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-24**:
Has this been completely resolved? I come across quite some links to `ros.org/docs/..` fi that `404` for me currently.

And `www.ros.org/wiki` leads to [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/) instead of redirecting. Not sure whether that was always the case, but it's confused students to no end here.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-11-26**:
I don't know the whole picture of what's going on but for redirection issue I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/237) for better visibility of the status.